# different implementations for abstract generic class

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have the following class:

```java
abstract class MyAbstract<T>
{
    T val_;
    MyAbstract(T val)
    {
        val_ = val;
    }
    T getVal()
    {
        return val_;
    }
}
```

I would like my abstract class to have a different body for T = String, for example (bear with me):

```java
abstract class MyAbstract<T extends String>
{
    T val_;
    T upperVal_;
    MyAbstract(T val)
    {
        val_ = val;
        upperVal_ = val.toUpperCase();
    }
    T getVal()
    { 
        return upperVal_; 
    }
}
```

The result I am trying to achieve is that if I extend MyAbstract, the second version will be used, otherwise the first one. Is this possible, and how? Thanks!

Update: I want to be able to extend the same abstract class and do stuff like:

```java
Type1 extends MyAbstract<Integer>...
```

and

```
Type2 extends MyAbstract<String>...
```

(note that I use `MyAbstract` for both Types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the second implementation `extend` the first.

```
abstract class MyAbstract2<T extends String> extends MyAbstract<T>
{
    T upperVal_;

    MyAbstract(T val)
    {
        super(val);
        upperVal_ = val.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    T getVal()
    { 
        return upperVal_; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve this while using the same name, so I can do stuff like `Type extends MyAbstract<blah>` and `Type2 extends MyAbstract<String>` (not create a second abstract type). I will update the question to specify this requirement.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. Why do you want to? What bigger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oh :( It was more of an academic question. I already have solutions for my problem, I am just trying to make the code more readable (at least according to my idea of readable :) )

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support template specialization like C++ does. In particular, all instances of a  generic class declaration share the same runtime class, and hence have the same set of fields.

Whatever you are trying to accomplish, you'll have to do it differently in Java.